# I need to SELECT a group of columns not null

Tags: sql, oracle

Basically, i have a table that have a series of columns named:

```
ATTRIBUTE10, ATTRIBUTE11, ATTRIBUTE12 ... ATTRIBUTE50
```

I want a query that gives me all the columns from `ATTRIBUTE10 to ATTRIBUTE50 not null`

Comment: The real problem here is your table design. Can you change that?

Comment: Please write a proper question

Comment: Are you saying you want every row where all columns 10 through 50 are not null, or something else?

Comment: @carviky13 . . . Your question is unclear.  Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I just want a proper query that doesn't need to write every single attribute manually. I can't change my table design and i have no foreign and primary key, i am on an Oracle Framework called MDM

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented we aren't exactly sure of your requirements, but if you want a list the  UNPIVOT can do that...

```
SELECT  attribute , value
FROM   
   (SELECT * from YourFile) p  
UNPIVOT  
   (value FOR attribute IN   
      (attribute1, attribute2, attribute3, etc.)  
)AS unpvt
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use where condition for all columns Or use between operator as below.

**For All Columns**

where ATTRIBUTE10 is not null and ATTRIBUTE11 is not null ...... and ATTRIBUTE50 is not null

**By using between operator**

where ATTRIBUTE10 between ATTRIBUTE11 and ATTRIBUTE50

Comment: Let's say that ATTRIBUTE10 = 5, ATTRIBUTE50 = 10, and ATTRIBUTE25 = 2716. How does your suggested use of `BETWEEN` handle this condition?

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach the problem is to unfold your table-with-a-zillion-like-named-attributes into one in which you've got one attribute per row, with appropriate foreign keys back to the original table. So something like:

```
CREATE TABLE ATTR_TABLE AS
SELECT ID_ATTR, ID_TABLE_WITH_ATTRS, ATTR
    FROM (SELECT ((ID_TABLE_WITH_ATTRS-1)*100)+1 AS ID_ATTR, ID_TABLE_WITH_ATTRS, ATTRIBUTE10 AS ATTR FROM TABLE_WITH_ATTRS UNION ALL
          SELECT ((ID_TABLE_WITH_ATTRS-1)*100)+2, ID_TABLE_WITH_ATTRS, ATTRIBUTE11 FROM TABLE_WITH_ATTRS UNION ALL
          SELECT ((ID_TABLE_WITH_ATTRS-1)*100)+3, ID_TABLE_WITH_ATTRS, ATTRIBUTE12 FROM TABLE_WITH_ATTRS);
```

This only unfolds ATTRIBUTE10, ATTRIBUTE11, and ATTRIBUTE12, but you should be able to get the idea - the rest of the attributes just requires a little cut-n-paste on your part.

You can then query this table to find your non-NULL attributes as

```
SELECT *
  FROM ATTR_TABLE
  WHERE ATTR IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY ID_ATTR
```

Hopefully the difficulty you're encountering in dealing with this table-with-a-zillion-repeated-fields teaches you a hard lesson about exactly *why* tables with repeated fields or groups of fields are a Bad Idea.

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d79debb0170e35dc78f724c9db43de1a)